# QUALIFY-like operation in MSSql, MySql, PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, google-bigquery

I have the following SQL code with a `QUALIFY` statement, which seems to be BigQuery.

```
SELECT A, B, sum(C), row_number()
over(partition by A order by sum(C) desc) as row_num
FROM mock_table
 group by 1,2
 QUALIFY row_num > 5
 order by 1
```

What should I use to achieve the same result in either MSSql, MySql or PSql?

Comment: For people that don't know BigQuery you should *explain* what the `QUALIFY` keyword does.

Comment: https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/qualify

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to reference a column alias in the WHERE clause is to use a derived table:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT A, B, sum(C), 
         row_number() over(partition by A order by sum(C) desc) as row_num
  FROM mock_table
  group by 1,2
) as t
where t.row_num > 5
order by a
```